# Copy only the contents of a directory into another directory

Tags: bash, copy

I want my bash script to copy the files inside the foo directory into the baz directory.

When I run this command in the terminal, it achieves what I expect:

```
cp -r /foo/. /baz
```

But when I save it as a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r /foo/. /baz
```

And run:

```
./script.sh
```

Then it unexpectedly copies the foo directory itself into baz (rather than only the files in foo).

What am I doing wrong? Why is this happening? How do I fix the bash script?

**Edit** - bad question. I ran an old version of my script without noticing. Everything does work as expected. The answers still helped me with alternative solutions.

Comment: It works for me, except that I used in both case : `cp -r foo/. baz` (removed first slash)

Comment: @jeanrjc - you are correct - see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rsync` instead. It doesn't copy the parent directory:

```
rsync -r /foo /baz
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the content of the script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp -r /foo/* /baz
```

To be honest, I'm not sure why you run into this issue. It works fine for me. Still, the asterisk seems more appropriate. Which OS are you running?

Comment: you are correct, there was no issue - see my edit.